# Does anyone have any Mathematica code for rainflow counting for fatigue and damage equivalent load anlaysis?

Tags: time-series

‘Rainflow Counting’ is a method to determine the number of fatigue cycles present in a load-time history.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainflow-counting_algorithm
There is a MatLab function that carries it out (https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rainflow.html).
It seems quite a complicated algorithm to code, so I was hoping someone out there has implemented something like it in mathematica.
Thanks !

Comment: I couldn't resist: https://pastebin.com/raw/1vrgds5n

Comment: :-).  well, actually, it is a start, but does not catch some of the subtleties.  Impressive though !